# loading file to WordPress page, content wrapped on divs and misplaceed

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to load an html file to populate part of my page template.

```
function mostSearched (){
    include '/mostsearched.html';
    $c = ob_get_clean();
    return $c;
}
```

But the output is wrapped on divs that break the template

> article#post-2.post-2.page.type-page.status-publish.hentry

The file content only has this:

```
XXXXXXXXXxx <br>
XXXXXXXXXxx <br>
XXXXXXXXXxx <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it with this

```
$c = file_get_contents('mostsearched.php');
return $c;
```

Thanks anyway!